# Specifying Entire Path As Optional Rails 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a Rails 3 route with entirely optional parameters. The example broken route is:

```
match '(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)' => 'people#index'
```

Which results in 'rake:routes' yielding:

> /(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)

And thus adding an initial slash to all links:

```
<a href="//name/kevin">...</a>
```

The route works if I specify it as:

```
match '/people(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)' => 'people#index'
```

But I want to have this as the root URL (as with the first example, which does not work). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer.  Admittedly, I'm still new to Rails 3 routes, but you have me stumped.

Comment: No worries. It looked like a solution going in :). I'm still stumped on the solution but thanks for the potential answer!

Comment: Can you give us several examples of the type of routes you want to see and what controllers they point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done with Rails' routing engine, but you can add a custom middleware to your stack and it should work just fine.

Put this in `lib/custom_router.rb`

```
class CustomRouter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['REQUEST_PATH'].match(/^\/(name|height|weight)/)
      %w(REQUEST_PATH PATH_INFO REQUEST_URI).each{|var| env[var] = "/people#{env[var]}" }
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

and add

```
 config.middleware.use "CustomRouter"
```

to your `config/application.rb`.

You can then set the route like

```
match '/people(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)' => 'people#index'
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use a separate root mapping?

```
root :to => 'people#index'
match '(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)' => 'people#index'
```

It does seem like a pretty major oversight in the new routing system.

There could be a way to hack it through a rack middleware (maybe overriding Rack::URLMap), but that's a little out of my league.

Comment: No, it does not work. Running rake:routes returns "/(/name/:name)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)" and the initial slash causes links to be "<a href="//name/kevin">...</a>".