# Sinatra app as Rails 3 subpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

I'm trying to get a sinatra app as a subpath in my rails 3 app.
Specifically, the resque queuing system has a sinatra based web interface that I would like to have accessible through /resque on my usual rails app.

You can see the project here: http://github.com/defunkt/resque

I found some people talking about adding a rackup file and doing this sort of thing:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new( \
  "/" => ActionController::Dispatcher.new,
  "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
)
```

But I don't really know where to put that or how to make it run. My deployment is with passenger, but it would me nice to also have it running when I run 'rails server' too. Any suggestions?

**--edit--**

I've made some progress by putting the following in config/routes.rb:

```
match '/resque(/:page)', :to => Rack::URLMap.new("/resque" => Resque::Server.new)
```

Which seems to work pretty well, however it loses the public folder, (which is defined within the gem I guess), and as a result, there is no styling information, nor images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup any rack endpoint as a route in rails 3. This guide by wycats goes over what you are looking for and many of the other things you can do in rails3:

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/

For example:

```
class HomeApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "Hello World!"
  end
end

Basecamp::Application.routes do
  match "/home", :to => HomeApp
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. But the URLs don't map to the root. I.e. all the urls passed to HomeApp start with '/home'. Is there a way to remap them?

Comment: Just replace `match "/home"` with `match "/"`?

Comment: That will map all the routes to the sinatra app. I want /resque/home to call /home in the sinatra app. The only solution I can think of is to mess with the Rack env and strip down the path.

Comment: OK I tried rewriting env['PATH_INFO'] and it breaks all the redirects, etc., so that probably won't work.

Comment: @zaius Maybe this'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026200/specifying-entire-path-as-optional-rails-3-0-0/3139056#3139056

Comment: @zaius I haven't played with it much, but I believe you would route /resque to the sinatra app, and it would handle /home itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yehuda (/Scott S)'s solution doesn't work for me with Rails 3.0.4 and Sinatra 1.2.1... setting `:anchor => false` in the matcher is the key:

```
# in routes.rb
match "/blog" => MySinatraBlogApp, :anchor => false

# Sinatra app
class MySinatraBlogApp < Sinatra::Base
  # this now will match /blog/archives
  get "/archives" do
    "my old posts"
  end
end
```

(answer c/o Michael Raidel - http://inductor.induktiv.at/blog/2010/05/23/mount-rack-apps-in-rails-3/)